# 3 nonzero distinct eigenvalues, part 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is an attempt to generalize the answer to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313544/why-does-this-matrix-have-3-nonzero-distinct-eigenvalues)

Consider the $n \times n$ matrix $$A=\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & \frac{1}{n-1} & ... & \frac{1}{n-1} \\ 
1 & 0 &  & 0 \\ 
\vdots  &  & \ddots  &  \\ 
1 & 0 &  & 0%
\end{array}%
\right] $$ (A has $n-1$ entries equal to $1/(n-1)$ in the first row, $n-1$ ones in the first column, and zeros anywhere else), and let $$G=A(I_n-\theta A)^{-1},$$ where $\theta$ is a scalar such that  $I_n-\theta A$ is invertible.

Let $W$ be a nontrivial subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ including the vector of all ones, and no other eigenvectors of $A$. Let $M$ be the orthogonal projector onto the orthogonal complement of $W$.

Let $$Q=G-\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{trace}(G) I_{n}.$$

Show that $$MQ+(MQ)^T$$ has exactly 3 nonzero distinct eigenvalues.

Numerical example:
$n=8$, $\theta=0.5$, $k=2$, $W$ spanned by $\iota_{n}=(1,1,...,1)^T$ and $(\iota_{n/2}^T,-\iota_{n/2}^T)^T$. Then $$MQ+(MQ)^T$$ has the following eigenvalues: $-\frac{2}{n}\mathrm{trace}(G)=-1/3$ with multiplicity $n-k-1=5$, and the 3 eigenvalues $0$, $-1.5122$, $0.0360$ with multiplicity 1.